# How to print a class object that extends from an abstract class in java

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, abstract-class

I need to create two model classes with same fields but the ELK indexname alone differs. Thus I created a abstract class with all the fields in it. The two model classes extend the abstract class.
I try to fetch records from the ELK index and the JSON response is returned fine by the application.I have log statements that print the model class objects. But the log statements print only object name with no fields and values set.
Please find the code below:
The model classes and the abstract class are below.

```
@Data
public abstract class Absmodel{
   public String name;
   public String department;
   public long salary;
}

@Data
@Document(indexName = "index1", createIndex = false)
public class Model1 extends Absmodel{

}

@Data
@Document(indexName = "index2", createIndex = false)
public class Model2 extends Absmodel{

}
```

The service class is as below.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ServiceDemo{
  @Autowired
  private Model1Repository model1Repo;

  @Autowired
  private Model2Repository model2Repo;
  
  public void getData(){
   
   List<Model1> model1List = model1Repo.getModel1data();
   Model2 model2Obj = model2Repo.getModel2data();
   log.info("The model1List is [{}]", model1List);
   log.info("The model2 object is [{}]", model2Obj);
  
  }

}
```

The output received:
**The model1List is [[Model1(), Model1(), Model1()]]**

**The model2Obj is [Model2()]**

The output expected:
**The model1List is [[Model1(name=Alex, department=EEE, salary=78364),Model1(name=Sam, department=ECE, salary=78364),Model1(name=Joe, department=IT, salary=78354)]]**

**The model2Obj is [Model2(name=Jim, department=IT,salary=8765)]**

What changes should I make in the code to get the class fields printed.

Comment: Have you tried verifying that the values were actually set?

Comment: Yes, the values are set and I am able to get the correct response for the API. Also, when I try to print model1Obj.getName(), the value gets printed.